# How to resolve Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'browsing-topics'?

Tags: html, google-chrome, privacy, ublock-origin

Just in the past couple days I have started getting console errors in chrome on my website that I'm developing on my local machine. The error is "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'browsing-topics'.

From brief googling, it seems to have something to do with Google's privacy settings for their new topics ad tracking thing. I am not using any ad related scripts on my website, so I don't know why it just suddenly started appearing. Can someone tell me how to get this to go away?

Edit - I figured out that the chrome extension uBlock origin is causing the error. I'd still like to figure out how to make it go away rather than just disabling uBlock origin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the uBlock Origin issue report](https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uBlock-issues/issues/2763) you can add the filter `@@||localhost^$permissions=browsing-topics=()` to your uBlock Origin filters to disable the messages.
However it should have been fixed in uBlock Origin in [this commit](https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets/commit/63ad5d6f098c4e515ecbb6b89f6b3ff373c146bb)

Comment: I did that and it didn't work. It's Nov 2023

Answer (score 50):

I disabled uBlock origin which removed the warning in the console

Comment: If I could I'd flag this as VLQ.

Answer (score 11):

You can hide the message by focusing on the current context / iframe.

In the Chrome console, clicking the Settings icon and enabling "Selected context only" will only show console messages from the currently selected iframe, or the top window.

[image: Console settings showing the "Selected context only" option]

But beware: if you're debugging a page with iframes, and you want to see console messages from those iframes, then you'll need to keep in mind which context you have selected.

Here is where you select your context. It lists all iframes and extensions (I'm not sure if these run in iframes or not)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Add the url of your development site to the Trusted sites in uBlock Origin settings.

Comment: This is actually the new solution for 2023, but it's identical with najim el guennouni's, which is to disable uBlock Origin for the web site, which does the same thing.